# count of repeating letters with count followed by letter

Tags: python-3.x

Given an input string like x = "aaabbbbaacdd", i am expecting an output like 3a4b2a1c2d. I am not sure what logic i can use beyond getting an index if x[element] != x[element+1]

```
for idx, val in enumerate(x[:-1]):
    if val != x[idx+1]:
        print(val, idx+1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic. I'd do something like this:

```
input = "aaabbbbaacdd"
current = input[0]
count = 1
output = ""
i=1;
for i in range(i,len(input)):
    if input[i] == current:
        count+=1
    else:
        output += (str(count) + current)
        current = input[i]
        count = 1

output += (str(count) + current)
print(output)
```

It returns as you had expected:

> 3a4b2a1c2d

Answer (score 0):

Use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter

x = "aaabbbbaacdd"

print(Counter(x))
```

This will print out the count of each unique item in the list:

```
Counter({'a': 5, 'b': 4, 'd': 2, 'c': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be done using while loop. here is the solution to the same (print can also be done in list form) -

```
x = "aaabbbbaacdd"
i = 0
count = 0
first = x[i]
out = ''
while i < len(x):
    if x[i]==first:
        count +=1
    else:
        out = out + str(count) + first
        first = x[i]
        count =1
    i +=1
out = out + str(count) + first
print(out)
```